# Minor typo in Help center AI policy

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

The [help center on AI policy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy) has a typo:

> 3. ven when generative artificial intelligence tools appear ...

I assume "ven" should be "Even":

> 3. Even when generative artificial intelligence tools appear ...

Comment: FWIW for something so small feel free to post a comment in [the 2nd](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595). We (mods) are regularly in the room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops. Fixed, thank you.

There was indeed an 'E' missing.